# Calculating product counts (efficiently) in faceted search with PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, faceted-search

Say I have a page that displays all available laptops in a webshop. These results can be refined by activating certain filters, such as brand, price, weight, amount of memory, disk space, like so:

```
Brand
[ ] Dell (16)
[ ] HP (12)
[ ] Lenovo (9)

Memory
( ) ≥ 2 GB (37)
( ) ≥ 4 GB (24)
( ) ≥ 8 GB (8)

Price
( ) ≤ 200 $ (3)
( ) ≤ 300 $ (12)
( ) ≤ 500 $ (22)
```

Currently, I'm calculating these product counts with a single query, the results of which I loop through in PHP to divide them into these categories (i.e. "Memory, ≥ 4 GB"). The problem with this approach is that when, for example, "≥ 4 GB" is selected and the results are shown, the product counts become illogical.

MySQL (simplified):

```
SELECT brand, memory, price FROM Laptops WHERE memory >= 4000
```

PHP (simplified):

```
while($row = msqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    if($row['memory'] >= 2000) {
        $product_count['memory']['2gb']++;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Memory
( ) ≥ 2 GB (24) <-- should be 37
(o) ≥ 4 GB (24)
( ) ≥ 8 GB (8)
```

Because now I'm using a query with a condition like `WHERE memory >= 4000`, the product counts are limited to the current 24 results (which match the activated filter), and so "≥ 2 GB" now has a count of 24 as well. It's true that of the 24 results, 24 will have 2 GB or more memory, but that's not relevant to the user, who needs to know how many results would be shown if 2 GB were selected.

I could query the database for each filter separately, leaving out the `WHERE` condition of that filter so that its product counts are unaffected by its own setting, but still affected by any other filters (like Brand). However, I plan on having at least a dozen filters, so that would result in a dozen more queries, putting a relatively large amount of extra strain on an otherwise fairly simple application.

Is there perhaps a more efficient way to calculate product counts, with fewer queries required?

Comment: maybe on php -> if($row['memory'] >= 2000 && $row['memory'] < 4000 )

Comment: Why are you using a where in your sql query when you are already filtering the result with php ? With your current sql query, there won't be any 2gb memory so the count of 2gb memory laptop is 0.

Comment: @MarcoMura The problem is that I'm working with a MySQL result set that's limited.

Comment: @redburn limited by what?

Comment: Sounds like you need a separate query

Comment: @Nico I'm not filtering the results with PHP, only calculating the product counts. You're right that there won't be any 2GB memory laptops among the current results, but since they're radio boxes the user should be able to switch to 2 GB and the product count should logically reflect the result of that.

Comment: @MarcoMura By the `WHERE` condition (i.e. the currently active filters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault in my thinking was that I would need an extra query for every possible filter to accurately calculate the product counts. However, the counts are only inaccurate for (radio) options in a currently selected filter (like Memory above), so if I simply recalculate product counts only for the active filters (by checking the current $_GET parameters), that drastically reduces the number of required queries.

So I'll have one query with all filters included, like:

```
$query = 'SELECT id, brand, memory, price, stock FROM Laptops 
          WHERE stock > 0 AND memory >= 4000 AND price <= 200';
```

I'll loop over that with PHP to divide the results into the filter categories and calculate their counts, and then for each active filter I'll *reset* those counts and recalculate them based on a query that has had that filter removed by a regex like `preg_replace('(AND memory >= \d+)','',$query);`.

```
$query = 'SELECT id, brand, memory, price, stock FROM Laptops 
          WHERE stock > 0 AND price <= 200';
```

Based on that query, the counts for Memory will now accurately reflect the results for each option, while still taking into account any of the other filters that are set (i.e. outside the scope of the memory filter):

```
Memory
( ) ≥ 2 GB (37)
(o) ≥ 4 GB (24)
( ) ≥ 8 GB (8)
```

Now users know that 4 GB limits the list to 24 items, and that switching to 2 GB will give more results.

If no filters are active, I won't need any extra queries to calculate the product counts. If the user does apply one or more filters, I'll only need one extra query for each of those, and I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your facet queries outside of any filters the user selects as the facet counts will never change. You are likely not doing this so when the user selects 4GB your query becomes:

```
SELECT brand, memory, price FROM Laptops WHERE memory >= 4000
```

When it should be:

```
SELECT brand, memory, price FROM Laptops WHERE memory >= 2000
```

I suggest you re-write your facet logic to not consider your filters and optimize your queries to do the count instead of doing it in PHP:

```
SELECT count(*) as total from Laptops WHERE memory >= 2000;
SELECT count(*) as total from Laptops WHERE memory >= 4000;
```

Alas, if you the user has multiple filters selected it will become more complicated as you likely do want to consider the other filters in queries that ARE NOT in the same facet section.

So... if faceted by brand only use this query for memory:

```
SELECT count(*) as total from Laptops WHERE memory >= 2000 and brand in ('HP', 'Dell');
SELECT count(*) as total from Laptops WHERE memory >= 4000 and brand in ('HP', 'Dell');
```

But for the brand facet for the same result set don't consider memory as it is not selected:

```
SELECT count(*) as total from Laptops WHERE brand = 'HP';
SELECT count(*) as total from Laptops WHERE brand = 'Dell';
SELECT count(*) as total from Laptops WHERE brand = 'Lenovo';
```

Alas, if filtering by brand and memory, consider both for price:

```
SELECT count(*) as total from Laptops WHERE price < 200 and memory between 2000 and 4000 and brand in ('HP', 'Dell);
```

Yes, getting everything right can be tricky espcially considering I did not cover the case that you probably only want one option selected for price but multiple for brand. That's why most people turn to http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ for faceted search which simply returns results set faceted by any fields you ask for.

Comment: Thanks for your time, you see my predicament. I looked into Solr but it would obviously be overkill to deploy it just for these product counts. I've now found a way with PHP/MySQL to (re)calculate the counts only for the active filters, because as you rightly say I "want to consider the other filters in queries that ARE NOT in the same facet section".

Answer (score -1):

I hope the problem might be the query let change the query to below mentioned and executed it.thank you

```
SELECT brand, memory, price FROM Laptops WHERE memory >= 2000
```